# Bootstrap col-lg being ignored and col-mg used instead for imac screen, desktop screen etc

Tags: grid

```
<div id="animatediv" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-1 animated zoomIn">
</div>
```

Please have a look:
https://memberkr.unicity-easynet.com/

Comment: Applying `xs`, `sm` and others depends on user's screen resolution. Check this one: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options. What is the resolution of your MAC?

Comment: the imac is like 2560-1440 it should be taking LG instead of md